# Insert Matching Names Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables CourtClekrs and Counties. Both of these have a column where the name of the county is stored. My intentions are the following

If column name matches insert the countyId value from the Counties table into the CourtClerk CountyId Column.

This is what I have so far but the FROM line is giving me an incorrect syntax error.

`INSERT INTO CourtClerks(CountyId) 
SELECT ck.CountyName as clerkCountyName, c.Name as CountyName
FROM CourtClerks ck, Counties c
WHERE ck.CountyName = c.Name`

I need a value that exists in the County table to be inserted into the empty

Comment: You can't do "insert ... from...", you have to do "insert ... select ... from ..."

Comment: It would be in SQL and the County Id would come from the ```County``` table

Comment: And you actually want `UPDATE` and not `INSERT` since there is already data in the table.

Comment: Try writing a select statement first to get all the rows you want to insert. Are you really trying to insert rows to CourtClerks with no columns entered other than County??? That seems a bit strange

Comment: ```INSERT INTO CourtClerks(CountyId) 
SELECT ck.CountyName as clerkCountyName, c.Name as CountyName
FROM CourtClerks ck, Counties c
WHERE ck.CountyName = c.Name``` Something like this is what I need

Comment: DUDE @SamiKuhmonen you are a genius. Sorry for asking such a dumb question. This is what solved my issue


```UPDATE CourtClerks
SET CountyId = c.CountyId 
FROM CourtClerks ck, Counties c
WHERE ck.CountyName = c.Name
```

Comment: You should start using the ANSI-92 style joins instead of the older style comma separated list of table names. It has been around for almost 30 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins